# sql query gives different result for PercentAnalysed

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The below is my query :

```
SELECT Runs.runId
    ,Runs.prodId
    ,passCount
    ,failCount
    ,CASE 
        WHEN failcount <> 0
            THEN cast((round(((counts.Count 100.0) / failcount), 0)) AS NUMERIC)
        WHEN failcount = 0
            OR ***counts.Count IS NULL
            THEN 100***
        ELSE 0
        END **PercentAnalysed**
FROM Runs AS Runs
INNER JOIN Product AS Product
    ON Runs.prodId = Product.prodId
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
        ,Results.runId
    FROM Results
    INNER JOIN Runs
        ON Results.runId = Runs.runId
    WHERE Analysed = 'True'
    GROUP BY Results.runId
    ) counts
    ON counts.runId = Runs.runId
```

My problem is that when counts.Count is NULL then Percent Analysed is not shown as 100.It is blank. (EDIT : According to the query as you can see when counts.Count is NULL then value for PercentAnalysed column should be 100 but it is shown as NULL )

Can someone tell me even why the condition in the CASE statement WHEN failcount = 0 OR counts.Count IS NULL THEN 100 doesn't work ?

Comment: It gives slightly different result than what? Give me a second I need to see into my crystall ball.

Comment: :P Sorry I have tried explaining in the question though.I'll give it another try :)

Comment: Can everyone please stop downvoting :P I am trying to explain..give me a minute please :)

Comment: krzysiej - Better now ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the expected result:

Change `failcount` to `NULL` if it's zero and change a `NULL` as result of the calculation back to `100`:

```
CAST(COALESCE(ROUND(((counts.COUNT * 100.0) / NULLIF(failcount, 0)), 0), 100) AS NUMERIC)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering dnoeth :) So,I replaced my case statement with what you have written above.The query now looks like this :

Comment: SELECT Runs.runId
    ,Runs.prodId
    ,passCount
    ,failCount
    ,CAST(COALESCE(ROUND(((counts.COUNT * 100.0) / NULLIF(failcount, 0)), 0), 100) AS NUMERIC) PercentAnalysed
FROM Runs AS Runs
INNER JOIN Product AS Product
    ON Runs.prodId = Product.prodId
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT() AS 'Count'
        ,Results.runId
    FROM Results
    INNER JOIN Runs
        ON Results.runId = Runs.runId
    WHERE Analysed = 'True'
    GROUP BY Results.runId
    ) counts
    ON counts.runId = Runs.runId

Comment: It gives an SQL execution error : Incorrect syntax near 'Count' and Incorrect syntax near the keyword AS

Comment: Regarding the 1st syntax error: there's no `count()` in SQL, should be `COUNT(*)` instead.  #2: `NUMERIC` is a synonym for `DECIMAL` in mysql, seems to be not allowed in a CAST, change to `DECIMAL` instead. Btw, both errors came from your original query, did this actually ever run?

Comment: Yes,my original query runs.The '*' in count got missed out while posting the question here and NUMERIC works with cast because my original query runs :)

Comment: Can u tell me even why the condition in the CASE statement WHEN failcount = 0 OR counts.Count IS NULL THEN 100 doesn't work ?

Comment: CASE stops at 1st WHEN returning TRUE, in your case you might have `failcount <> 0` and `count` with NULL. Changing the order of WHENs should fix it.

Comment: Nailed it ! Thanks a ton :)